# u-boot-tools mkimage does not allow me to build an arm64 image

Tags: linux, u-boot, arm64

I am trying to boot a linux image 64 using uboot. I managed to compile the linux kernel but now I can not seem to find a way to make a arm64 uImage ( I have found only the arm option)
From what I gathered so far I saw that arm64 is rather new and Ubuntu tends to have old packages ( for stability or something ).

What I would like is to find some updated package for u-boot-tools or a way to compile from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source for u-boot-tools is in DENX u-boot [git repository](http://www.denx.de/en/Software/GIT), tools/ directory. Build instructions are in [README](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=blob_plain;f=README) and/or separate google search.

In git history (e.g. common/image.c) I see "arm64: core support" 
came in 2013-12-13, hence would be in u-boot release v2014.01 and later. [Looks](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=u-boot-tools) like it would be absent from debian wheezy, but present in jessie and later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an image with mkimage.
Instead, use the `booti` command on U-Boot prompt to load a regular kernel, like is described at http://elinux.org/R-Car/Boards/Salvator-X in the "Booting Linux" section (excerpt from the page):

```
tftpboot 0x48080000 Image
tftpboot 0x48f00000 r8a7795-salvator-x.dtb (for R-Car H3)
tftpboot 0x48f00000 r8a7796-salvator-x.dtb (for R-Car M3-W)
booti 0x48080000 - 0x48f00000
```